# Confused with name, id, onclick, onsubmit - what am i doing wrong in submitting data in db?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

My code given below. Please help me correct the code. Iam confused with syntax. Also I do not know where exactly to put error message alert if there is any database issue and how to close the database. Please help

```
<form id="ContactForm" name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="submitdata()">
  <div>
    <div class="formwrap"><span>Your Name:</span><input name="fname" type="text" class="input" ></div>
    <div class="formwrap"><span>Your E-mail:</span><input type="text" name="femail" class="input" ></div>
    <div class="formwrap"><span>Your Mobile:</span><input type="text" name="fmobile" class="input" ></div>
    <div class="formwrap"><span>Your City:</span><input type="text" name="fcity" class="input" ></div>
    <div class="textarea_box"><span>Your Message:</span><textarea name="fmessage" cols="1" rows="1"></textarea></div>
    <a class="button" onClick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').submit()"><span class="shadow"></span>Send</a>
    <a class="button" onClick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').reset()"><span class="shadow"></span>Clear</a>
  </div>
</form>


<?php
function submitdata(){
  include "config/connection.php";
  $fdname = $_POST['fname']);
  $fdemail = $_POST['femail']);
  $fdmobile = $_POST['fmobile']);
  $fdcity = $_POST['fcity']);
  $fdmessage = $_POST['fmessage']);

  $sql="INSERT INTO users (name, email, mobile, city, message)
  VALUES ('$fdname', '$fdemail', '$fdmobile', '$fdcity', '$fdmessage')";
}
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please try delete every ")" at the end of each $_POST. `$fdname = $_POST['fname']);` => `$fdname = $_POST['fname'];`

Comment: Another issue is that you're trying to call a PHP function on form submit like it's a Javascript function.  PHP runs on the server, not the client.

Comment: i dont know what and how to use among ajax javascript php. can you help me correct the code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the action on your html form and created the php script that will handle and store your data into the database,take a look and do some further reading on prepared statements.

```
<form id="ContactForm" name="form1" action="insert.php" method="post">
  <div>
    <div class="formwrap"><span>Your Name:</span><input name="fname" type="text" class="input" ></div>
    <div class="formwrap"><span>Your E-mail:</span><input type="text" name="femail" class="input" ></div>
    <div class="formwrap"><span>Your Mobile:</span><input type="text" name="fmobile" class="input" ></div>
    <div class="formwrap"><span>Your City:</span><input type="text" name="fcity" class="input" ></div>
    <div class="textarea_box"><span>Your Message:</span><textarea name="fmessage" cols="1" rows="1"></textarea></div>
    <a class="button" onClick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').submit()"><span class="shadow"></span>Send</a>
    <a class="button" onClick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').reset()"><span class="shadow"></span>Clear</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
    if($_POST){
        $db = new mysqli("address","id","password","DBname");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
            exit();
        }

        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, email, mobile, city, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt -> bind_param('sssss', $fname, $femail, $fmobile, $fcity, $fmessage);

        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $femail = $_POST['femail'];
        $fmobile = $_POST['fmobile'];
        $fcity = $_POST['fcity'];
        $fmessage = $_POST['fmessage'];

        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> close();
        $db -> close();
        }
?>
```

Comment: great!. this did it. however, it goes to insert.php file and shows a blank screen on the browser whereas i need to return to the form. Is there a way to give user an alert that data added successfully and stay on the form itself?

Comment: Place the html code inside insert.php and use this as the form page,also change `$stmt -> execute();` to `$result = $stmt -> execute();` and after `$db -> close();`add  `if(!$result) echo "<script> alert('data added successfully'); </script>";`

Comment: thanx but i dont want to shift my html code as this form is just one small part of my big html page and i cannot shift the entire html page. is there any other solution?

Comment: Use your html page as is then and add `header("Location: http://yoursite.com");` after `$db -> close();` at the insert.php file.

Comment: Thanks. I did that and after adding header after dbclose, i also added an alert box echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Message sent successfully. Thank you!');</script>"; Now the data gets added but I get error Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /.../.../.../.../insert.php:20) in /.../.../.../.../insert.php on line 23. If I remove alert, it works properly. Any idea how can I get alert without the error popping up?

Comment: Replace both header()/alertbox with this
`echo "<script>
alert('Message sent successfully. Thank you!');
window.location.replace('http://yoursite.com');
</script>";`

Answer (score 0):

For `onsubmit` `attribute` JS `function` or codes is required not PHP `function`. But you provided a PHP `function` in `onsubmit`. I suggest you to use `AJAX` or `action` in `form`.

An Example for you

```
<form id="ContactForm" name="form1" >
    <div>
        <div class="formwrap"><span>Your Name:</span><input name="fname" type="text" class="input" ></div>
        <div class="formwrap"><span>Your E-mail:</span><input type="text" name="femail" class="input" ></div>
        <div class="formwrap"><span>Your Mobile:</span><input type="text" name="fmobile" class="input" ></div>
        <div class="formwrap"><span>Your City:</span><input type="text" name="fcity" class="input" ></div>
        <div class="textarea_box"><span>Your Message:</span><textarea name="fmessage" cols="1" rows="1"></textarea></div>
        <a class="button" id="submit"><span class="shadow"></span>Send</a>
        <a class="button" onClick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').reset()"><span class="shadow"></span>Clear</a>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#submit').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        data: $('#ContactForm').serialize(),
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data){
            if(data == 'inserted'){
                alert('Inserted');
            }else{
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**In `test.php`**

```
include "config/connection.php";
$fdname = $_POST['fname'];
$fdemail = $_POST['femail'];
$fdmobile = $_POST['fmobile'];
$fdcity = $_POST['fcity'];
$fdmessage = $_POST['fmessage'];

$sql="INSERT INTO users (name, email, mobile, city, message)
VALUES ('$fdname', '$fdemail', '$fdmobile', '$fdcity', '$fdmessage')";

// if you use mysql connection
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result) {
  echo 'inserted';
} else {
  die(mysql_error());
}
```

You also fix some `syntax error`. Remove `)` after each `$_POST`.

Comment: My objective is to send the form data to database table without loading another page or shifting the current page position. Once Send button is clicked, the data should go in database. The code is my own research on google but it did not work. i dont know how to use ajax php javascript for this small piece of info to be sent to db. can you help me here?

Comment: im using mysql connection and i used the lower part of the code. nothing happens when i click on send button. i checked my config/connection.php file and its correct. it just refreshes the page

Comment: Why you used lower part. Use both parts & test. I changed both parts. It works.

Comment: I got confused with this statement that you commented // if you use mysql connection.... It works. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this (if you have jQuery included):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form[name=form1]').submit(function () {
        var fname = $('input[name=fname]').val();
        var femail = $('input[name=femail]').val();
        var fmobile = $('input[name=fmobile]').val();
        var fcity = $('input[name=fcity]').val();
        var fmessage = $('textarea[name=fmessage]').val();
        $.post("/ajax/insert.php", {
            'fname': fname,
            'femail': femail,
            'fmobile': fmobile,
            'fcity': fcity,
            'fmessage': fmessage
        }, function (data) {
            if (data == 1) {
            alert("Success");
            } else {
            alert("Error");
            }
        });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then make folder "ajax" in the root of website and make there a script called insert.php (if you want different name, edit line 9 in the js code). Content of the insert.php will be something like this:

```
<?php
  include "config/connection.php";
  $fdname = $_POST['fname'];
  $fdemail = $_POST['femail'];
  $fdmobile = $_POST['fmobile'];
  $fdcity = $_POST['fcity'];
  $fdmessage = $_POST['fmessage'];

  $sql="INSERT INTO users (name, email, mobile, city, message)
  VALUES ('$fdname', '$fdemail', '$fdmobile', '$fdcity', '$fdmessage')";

  mysql_query($sql);
  if(mysql_error()) {
      echo 0;
  } else {
      echo 1;
  }
?>
```

Comment: I was trying the other solution provided by user3659034. I used your code too but nothing happens when i click on send button. i checked my config/connection.php file and its correct. it just refreshes the page. I added an alert in the submit(function () before var fname= but that alert is also not coming. that means it is not going in the fuction

Comment: It's probably because you don't have jQuery included. First you need to include jQuery, before this code.